# Why can't I see a control that I have created dynamically through reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I am trying to get to grips with reflection because I want to be able to load a third party assembly from my assembly, dynamically create a control from that third party assembly and then display it in a form that I create.

I have read various bits of the msdn documentation, blog posts, google search results etc and by dint of experimentation have got this far.  In the code below AcmeControls is the third party Assembly and AcmeLabel is the control I wish to create which has a Text property with both a get and set.  I know exactly where the third party assembly is going to be found so there is a separate function to determine that (which isn't shown below for clarity).

```
Public Sub CreateDynamicLabelViaReflection()
    Dim type As System.Type
    Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(GetAssemblyName("AcmeControls.dll"))
    Dim obj As System.Object


    type = asm.GetType("AcmeControls.AcmeLabel")
    obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, New Object() {})
    Dim textProp As PropertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Text")
    Dim textPropSet As MethodInfo = textProp.GetSetMethod

    Dim newAl As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
    textPropSet.Invoke(newAl, New Object() {"here is my text"})


    Dim frm As New Form With {.Text = "Hello"}
    frm.Controls.Add(newAl)
    frm.Show()

    For Each ctrl As Control In frm.Controls
        MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Location.ToString) 'ctrl.GetType.ToString here returns AcmeLabel
    Next

End Sub
```

I then have a separate project that references the assembly that this code is in and in in a button click event in that project it calls CreateDynamicLabelViaReflection().

What I end up with is a form but with no visible indication that the AcmeLabel is present on the form.  However nor does it throw any errors so I assumed that this code was probably working in part, which led me to add the For each loop at the bottom.  Sure enough there is a control in the forms control collection and it is an AcmeLabel (with Location X = 0, y = 0).  However I can't see it or the text that in theory I had added to it earlier.

I've clearly missed an important step somewhere but I'm not sure what that step is, could someone help me to understand the process better?

Thanks

Comment: `newSl` != `newAl`.  Use Option Strict to eliminate errors like this.  the label is there it just has no text, no BG color and no border, so it is effectively invisible

Comment: That was a typo in my post which I've now edited, thanks for pointing it out, Option Strict is On.

Comment: Does that mean the error was in the post only?  Option Strict cant be on with that code as there would be a type conversion error as it is posted.

Comment: I changed the name of the variables for the code that I posted just to make it a little more readable, Option strict is on in the real thing and it doesn't throw any type conversion errors.  Indeed I had wondered initially if the fact that it was on might have been an issue as several bits that I've read suggest that it needs to be Off when doing reflection, so I tried it with Option Strict Off as well. can for example have ctrl.Text.ToString in the MessageBox.Show line and it will return 'here is my text' so I'm fairly sure that the label is there I just can't see it.

Comment: there is always the chance there is something goofy with the DLL. Use a plain old regular `Label` to see. The type error: `Dim newAl As Object` then `frm.Controls.Add(newAl)` you cant add type Object to a controls collection, only Control.

Comment: Doh!  I'm an idiot.  AcmeLabel has a size property and an AutoSize Property. Both of these need to be actively set as well when using reflection otherwise it has a size of (0,0) or to all intents and purposes invisible.  Thanks for your help, it made me try the same with another Acme control which did get shown with the same basic syntax, prompting me to look closer into what might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

make this chanc=ge in your code

```
   Dim frm As New Form With {.Text = "Hello"}
   frm.Controls.Add(newAl)
   newA1.visible=true
   frm.Show()
```

Comment: @Dom Sinclair: is it visible now?

Comment: Hi Sujith.  Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately that simply doesn't work.  The AcmeLabel does have a visible property (which by default is set to true) so my assumption has been that I would not need to explicitly set this particular property via reflection.